# Newly added icons on flutter web are invisible

Tags: html, flutter, dart, web, caching

When adding new icons to a flutter web app, presumably the old icon font stays in cache, so any new icons appear invisible:

[image: Icon missing in the button]

After clearing cache with browser's devtools, the icon appears as expected:

[image]

I suspect the old icon font is being stored in browser's cache. My question is how to remove it from cache of all the users using my website if i decide to add new icons?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Make a flutter app with one icon:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.abc),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

2. Build the app with `flutter build web` and upload the app to a web hosting. Works as expected:

[image: Website with abc icon]

3. Update the app code, adding a new, different icon:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Icon(Icons.abc),
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                label: const Text('foo'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ElevatedButton was added to demonstrate that it's not the app code not being updated, but the icon font.

4. Add a cache-busting string in web/index.html

```html
...
  <script src="flutter.js?v=1" defer></script>
...
```

5. Upload the app to the same website.

The button is there, but the newly added icon is invisible:
[image: Icon missing in the button]

6. After clearing cache with browser's devtools, looks as expected:

[image]

I tried looking through web/index.html for a way to make user re-download the new icon font, couldnt find any links to the icons.
I've googled about this issue and found similar articles, but they were talking about migrating to a new flutter version and the *incorrect* icons being shown, which is not the issue im having.

Comment: try adding a cache-busting string to the icon font file

Comment: That would be neat, but unfortunately I cannot find any mentions of the icon file in web/index.html. Can you show me where to put it, exactly?